# What is the status of Vladimir Romanov's proof that P=NP?

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, p-vs-np

A couple of months ago there was a minor hubbub about a paper published on ArXiV by V. F. Romanov titled [*Non-Orthodox Combinatorial Models Based on Discordant Structures*](http://arxiv.org/abs/1011.3944) which claimed to give a polynomial-time algorithm for 3-SAT, thus proving that $P=NP$. He even went as far as posting a [reference implementation](https://github.com/anjlab/sat3) of the algorithm publicly.

However, as is usually the case with these things, the public attention didn't last long enough for me to hear of any resolution to this claim. I assume this means it *wasn't* successful, obviously, so does anybody know what the problem with this paper ended up being?

Comment: Can you explain why the downvote?

Comment: I should perhaps emphasize that, at the time, it was considered a serious attempt (despite the unusual result), and *not* one of the many crackpot claims out there.

Comment: The question seems to be [in scope according to the FAQ](http://meta.cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/274/is-it-ok-to-ask-about-the-correctness-of-preprints-on-crank-friendly-topics/281#281), but you would probably get a better answer if the question was focused on some particular technical claim.

Comment: @arnab: Thanks for that; I hadn't seen those guidelines since they're on the Meta site and not the FAQ (yet). I'll try to edit my question soon with some concrete technical points from the article.

Comment: Please see [this FAQ item](http://meta.cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/274/is-it-ok-to-ask-about-the-correctness-of-preprints-on-crank-friendly-topics/281#281). General questions about correctness of an unpublished not-peer-reviewed pre-print claiming to solve an open problem is off-topic for this site.

Comment: Okay, having read the policy, I understand the reason for closing, but I humbly submit that a question on a neighboring website from 7 months ago is not really an "FAQ item" that you should expect new users to have read before posting.

Comment: @Adrian, there is a link to it in [the official FAQ](http://meta.cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/225/official-faq-for-theoretical-computer-science) (last item). We are here to remind the new users about the policies of this site. :)

Comment: @Adrian: meta.cstheory is not just a "neighbouring" website. It is _the_ site where the policy of cstheory is decided. This is a feature of _all_ stackexchanges sites. Every site has a corresponding meta, and browsing the questions tagged [faq] will serve you well on the main site.